# Help with basic Python function

Tags: python

I have a function to connect to a database. This code works:

```
def connect():
    return MySQLdb.connect("example.com", "username", "password", "database")
```

But this doesn't:

```
def connect():
    host = "example.com"
    user = "username"
    pass = "password"
    base = "database"
    return MySQLdb.connect(host, user, pass, base)
```

Why so?

Comment: up vote for using the "beginner" tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pass` is a reserved keyword.

Pick different variable names and your code should work fine.
Maybe something like:

```
def connect():
   _host = "example.com"
   _user = "username"
   _pass = "password"
   _base = "database"
   return MySQLdb.connect(_host, _user, _pass, _base)
```

Comment: Haha, didn't realize. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, got tripped up by syntax highlighting. Corrected.

Comment: the convention is to *append* `_` to the keyword. When you prepend, it means it's a private variable.

Comment: @Bastien True. Considering the placement of the vars, I assumed private.